# What is the Spatial Datatype used for?

Tags: mysql

I've googled this and cannot find a good enough answer.

What exactly are the Spatial Datatype (Geometry, point, multipoint) used for?

Comment: Did you go through this? [Spatial Data Types Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) it seems to have very good explanation

Comment: @MaryamArshi I did, but I didn't fully understand what was being said there.

Comment: I guess the short answer is "to make faster/more efficient/more convenient queries with geometrical data", no?

Comment: Things like routes from Home to Holiday chalet in satnav.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these types for anything that has a coordinate system, latitude and longitude for positions on the earth, customer locations or areas are typical usesof geography types. You can also keep arbitrary coordinates for anything that has x,y style dimensions, a floor plan of a building, a wiring diagram or a CAD model, if you wanted to, with geometry types.

The real power of spatial data types comes in to play when you have a spatial index on the data - this allows queries to be made like "find me the nearest..." Or "what's the distance between ..." Very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A space filling curve is an example for a spatial index method. Mathematically it's H(x,y)=(h(X), h(Y)). It's a curve that fills the surface completely and also subdivide it. It's also reduce the dimension and because it's a curve it traverse only adjacent cells. It's similar to a quadtree spatial index which is also often use for nearest-neighbor search. Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database